# If statement working when a variable is activated by one script, but not another

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Essentially, I am using Unity C#, (I am very new, so I may be missing something obvious), and I have a script, which uses Raycast to "talk to" NPCs.

Essentially what it then does, is the Raycast picks up what it collided with, and then opens the "NPC" script inside that object. I do this to differentiate the NPCs, as in the future I can change the code for different NPCs using Serialization.

Okay, again this also works fine based on my debugging, my problem seems to be happening further ahead.

This NPC script then activates a variable on another my "NPCMaster" script called "DialogueActive". According to my debugging this also works, the problem is, is that despite both my NPCs being pretty much exactly the same, and are both correctly activating this variable one of them will not activate the if statement checking if "DialogueActive" == true.

The odd thing is, when I change their names, to both the same name, or change their names completely, or delete, and copy the prefab, the broken NPC changes. Yet once I place them, one NPC is broken and the other isn't, it is not depending on who I talk to first or anything. And I can talk to the non-broken NPC as many times as I want and it will always work.

I have tried a bunch of things, I have tried changing how I activate the variable (despite it not being where the problem begins) I have tried deleting them both, duplicating them, making them have the same name, but then the broken NPC will just switch places.

Like I said, I am new to C# unity, and pretty much coding in general so the problem likely results from my ignorance.

//The if statement where the problem happens.

```
void Update()
{
    if (DialogueActive == true)
    {
        Debug.Log("Test2");
        panelexist.enabled = true;

        maintext.text = dialogue;
    }
    else
    {
        panelexist.enabled = false;
        maintext.text = ""; 
    }
}
```

//The variable which activates the "DialogueActive" variable.

```
void Update()
{
    if (Interacting == true)
    {
        Debug.Log("Test1");
        obj.GetComponent<NPCMasterScr> ().DialogueActive = true;
    }
    else 
    {
        obj.GetComponent<NPCMasterScr> ().DialogueActive = false;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyUp("escape"))
    {
        Interacting = false;
        obj.GetComponent<NPCMasterScr> ().DialogueActive = false;
    }
}
```

I expected the if (DialogueActive == true) statement to activate the code below it, which it did in one case but not another.

Comment: Care to show us your declarations for DialogueActive?  A MCVE would be nice

Comment: No idea what a "MCVE" is but here is where DialogueActive was declared in my NPCMaster script. `public bool DialogueActive = false; `

Comment: This line: `obj.GetComponent<NPCMasterScr> ().DialogueActive = false;` What script contains it? "NPC"?

Comment: @Nitro557 That is done by the “NPC” script and it is changing the DialogueActive variable, which is stated in the “NPCMaster” script, the same script that contains the if statement, using the the DialogueActive variable. I have put that if statement in my original post. I could post the entire script if you want but its mostly unrelated.

Comment: @LiamMcCoy, ok. So, you currently have 2 objects with NPCMasterScr on the scene?

Comment: @Nitro557 In my OC the bottom code block is from the “NPC” script. This script is in both my NPC’s the ones I interact with with raycast. So there is two instances of the NPC script. The top code block, is from “NPCMaster” which there is only one instance, in a empty in my entire scene.

Comment: @LiamMcCoy, okay, it's clear for me now, thanks

Comment: @Nitro557 Your welcome.

Comment: @LiamMcCoy, so, there's two objects on the scene with the "NPC" scripts, right? And one “NPCMaster” script. If you disable one of "NPC" script, the last one working correctly then?

Comment: @Nitro557 One of the NPC script works, while the other does not, while both are activated. For example. I have one NPC script in Bill, and the other in John. Bill will work while John will not. Or the other way around. But once I place Bill, or John in the editor, one will always work, no matter who I talk to in the game. I am explaining it terrible, but its hard to explain. But yes one NPCMaster script and two NPC scripts.

Comment: @Nitro557 However, both of them activate DialogueActive fine. The problem happens when trying to detect whether DialogueActive is true through the if statement. Or at least that is what I have found when debugging.

Comment: If you are just new to unity you could use some triggers instead of raycast. It's more easy to use :)

Comment: @LiamMcCoy a MCVE is a minimum complete verifiable example as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example producing one gives us the ability to reproduce and debug your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your scripts doing some conflicting things.

This part:

```
 if (Interacting == true)
    {
        Debug.Log("Test1");
        obj.GetComponent<NPCMasterScr> ().DialogueActive = true;
    }
    else 
    {
        obj.GetComponent<NPCMasterScr> ().DialogueActive = false;
    }
```

This will work correctly on the script that is higher in the hierarchy. 
When the second script trying to do something when if = true, the first script blocking this via its `else`. So, when the second script trying to `obj.GetComponent<NPCMasterScr> ().DialogueActive = true;`, the first script does `obj.GetComponent<NPCMasterScr> ().DialogueActive = false;`.

**Update 1:**
The following code may help to understand the problem.

```
void Update()
{
    if (Interacting == true)
    {
        Debug.Log("Test1");
        obj.GetComponent<NPCMasterScr> ().DialogueActive = true;
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("escape"))
    {
        Interacting = false;
        obj.GetComponent<NPCMasterScr> ().DialogueActive = false;
    }
}
```

HOW-TO-USE:

- Interact with the firs object
- Stop interacting
- Press Esc (interacting should be stopped before this step!)
- Interact with the second object

... and control `DialogueActive` state for each step

Comment: Thank you! How would I go about doing this differently then?